# In sage's solve function, is there a way to express a disjoint conditional?

Tags: sage

Take the following combination of constraints, for example:

```
var('x y', domain='real')
constraint1 = x^2 + y^2 == 1
constraint2 = x==y OR x==-y

solve([constraint1, constraint2],x,y)
```

This of course does not work, because OR is invalid syntax. Is it possible to mark disjoint constraints as input to `sage`'s solve function?

Comment: I believe `solve` only accepts basic simultaneous systems of equations. You will likely need to either create clever equation that captures the "OR" (e.g. `x == abs(y)` for this example), or make separate calls to `solve` for each variation of the equations.